# What is the correct way to perform a greaterThan comparison using assertThat and Hamcrest?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

Test Case - see the comment `//won't compile`

```
@Test
public void testHamcrestLongandInt(){
    int x = 100;
    long y = 50;
    //won't compile:
    assertThat(x, is(greaterThan(y)));

    //alternatives that do compile/work.
    assertThat(Long.valueOf(x), is(greaterThan(y)));
    assert (x > y);
    //most readable?

}
```

I like the type safety that prevents the `assertThat(x, is(greaterThan(y)));` from compiling. However the Long.valueOf(x), is also odd looking when compared to the simplicity of assert(x > y);.  In the actual test I am using returned types from the Spring Data Framework.

- Page.getTotalElements() returns a long
- Pageable.pageSize is an integer

My Test was making sure the total elements was larger than the pageSize.